# Question about Irreducible Polynomials Being Relatively Prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Question: Let $k$ be any field, and $f; g \in k[x; y]$ irreducible polynomials, not multiples of one another. Write $K = k(x)$; prove  that $f; g$ have no common factors in the PID $K[y]$.

My interpretation: I assume by no common factors, it is meant that $f,g$ are co-prime in $K[y]$ and thus we can find $a,b\in K[y]$ such that $af+bg=1$.

My thoughts: I would try to deduce it from definitions but I'm not sure how to manipulate the information that $f,g$ are irreducible polynomials of two variables because I cannot just say consider some field extension where they both factor linearly.

My only seemingly legitimate attempt would be: Let $h$ be the gcd of $f,g$ in $K[y]$ then there exist $a,b \in K[y]$ such that $af+bg=h$. I'm not sure where to go from here since I am not sure what I know about $f,g$ in $K[y]$. Are they irreducible still, etc...?

Extra Questions: Is $K[y]$ which is $k(x)[y]$ an extension of $k[x,y]$. How should I think about $k(x)[y]?$

Comment: Is $k(x)$ different from $k[x]$ ? (What does $k(x)$ mean ?)

Comment: $k(x)$ is the field of rational expressions/functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Gauss' Lemma $f,g$ remain irreducible in $K[y]$, hence are coprime.

By the way, this easily implies that $V(f,g) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ is finite.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of a reference for this particular lemma of Gauss? He seem's to have quite a few ;)

Comment: Is it somehow equivalent to irreducibility lemma on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)

If so, I'm struggling a bit to see the connection.

Comment: @ricky: It's the same Lemma that tells us that a univariate polynomial that is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ remains so in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: So the idea here is that since $k[x,y]$ is the same as $k[x][y]$ we think of $f,g$ as irreducible in $k[x][y]$ which implies irreducible in $k(x)[y]$ where $k[x]$ is the ring playing the role of the integers and $k(x)$ is its field of fractions playing the role of the rationals?

Comment: @ricky: That's the one, look up the item :" a proof valid in any GCD domain"

Comment: Follow up: So, if two polynomials are irreducible they cannot share a non-constant component. Suppose they did, then if that component were of smaller degree than the degree of the polynomials they could not be irreducible. This forces the two polynomials in question to be of the same degree (in $y$) and that this common component is as well. Call this common component $h\in K[y]$, then it follows that $g=\alpha h$ and also that $f=\beta h$ where $\alpha, \beta \in K=k(x)$. But then $g=\alpha/\beta f$. I am not sure how to get a contradiction. It seems reasonable that they share a component.